# Swift Error Xcode 7 - AnyObject

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, touchesbegan

I have created an app called Nimble Ninja and have an error when running, I have tried to fix it but when I do the game doesn't work properly. Please can someone help me?

Here is the part of code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if isGameOver {
        restart()
    }else if !isStarted {
        start()
    }else {
        hero.flip()
    }
}
```

I have tried to use:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if isGameOver {
        restart()
    }else if !isStarted {
        start()
    }else {
        hero.flip()
    }
}
```

However it does run the program but not as I would like. Please can someone help me use

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

this in xcode 7. 
Thanks
ZeApp Coding

Comment: What is the problem ? Are you getting any error ? What you mean by *However it does run the program but not as I would like* ?

Comment: You're literally giving us _nothing_ to go on. As Midhun MP asks, _what_ is your problem? A (truly) _wild_ guess would be that you are handling too many different states and that this messes up the flow you're trying to achieve...

Comment: It's a game where a character runs across the screen. Objects appear on the screen and to dodge them you have to tap the screen. I use to use the top code and that would work as the character could go up and down the running platform. However when Xcode was updated it didn't run so I tried the code with set UITouch but it doesn't go back up onto the running platform it just a keeps going down the screen not up and then down and visa versa. Thanks